# How to create intranet document search

Tags: email, search, search-engine, wiki

I'm trying to put together the following system, and I'd like some advice, from "don't do it" to "just install X and it will do it"

Stage 1: have a folder somewhere dedicated to documents. Anyone from the team can put files there, edit files, create folders, etc. Let this location be indexed by a search-engine, e.g. Solr and thus accessible.
Q: Do I need some special indexing/crawling system separate from the search engine?

Stage 2: have a bot mail-user that whenever it receives e-mail, it stores it in said folder.
Q: Is this easy to do? We use outlook exchange, but we have also Linux servers if it makes things easier.

Stage 3: add some logic while storing the e-mails: e.g. put same-subject e-mails in the same folder.
Q: How do you do that?

Thanks